# Protractor : Even though the toggle is ON/OFF, my code always returning false value

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am using protractor to automate web UI. I need to verify If the toggle is ON, it should return True and it should come out from the loop, If it False it should enable the toggle.

Below is the image which I am automating:

[image]

Below is the code using for automation. but every time isSelected() returning false, even though the toggle is ON.

```
turnONSwitchButton.isSelected().then(function (selected) {
            console.log(selected);
                if (!selected)
                {
                    browser.sleep(3000);
                    turnONSwitchButton.click().
                    console.log("switch ON");
                
                }
                else{
                    console.log("switch OFF");
                }
            })
```

Comment: Please provide the code of turnONSwitchButton and isSelected.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how are your toggle button was implemented, you will need to give an example.

In some cases it will return true or false always if you use **isSelected()**. You should probably look into in html tag, if it has any attribute and its value is changing e.g checked=true and checked=false. in that case you can use

```
toogleButton.getAttribute("checked").then(isSelected =>{
  if(isSelected == ('true'))
      log("Checked");
  else 
      log("Not Checked");
});
```